# Accessing static member variable from class instance

Tags: class, c#-4.0, member, static-members

Given the following

```
class Foo
{
    public static int Bar { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    var foo = new foo();

    //Erroneous member access here
    var value = foo.Bar;

    //Correct member access here
    var value = Foo.Bar;
}
```

Q: Why can one not access a static variable via an instance of that class - The object itself is after all allowed to access static member variables from with-in its own procedural calls.

Comment: There's only *one* implementation of the Bar property since you declared it *static*.  Using "foo.Bar" makes little sense, the property value does not depend on the value of "foo" at all.  So the compiler tweaks your nose, thinking that you are making a common object-oriented programming mistake.  You are.  Notable is that VB.NET allows this syntax, maybe you're more comfortable with that language.

Comment: @HansPassant - your comment doesn't hold much relevance as it doesn't state why the language restricts it to such an extent.

And also don't tell me which language I might be better suited for. I stated nothing about my preference for syntax